# Twitter Follower count number PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, twitter

I would like to display the amount of Followers a Twitter Page.
I am using the following code, but I keep getting the error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" on line `echo $tweet->followers_count;` I have tried a var_dump on `$tweetsshow` and `followers_count` is shown.

```
$tweetsshow = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser);

foreach($tweetsshow as $tweet)
{
    echo $tweet->followers_count;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: echo <pre> before your var_dump and </pre> after it, re-add the output you get so it's readable. You are not going deep enough your entity it's something like $tweet->entities->followers_count

Comment: I tried the <pre> you suggested, however the output remained the same. I'm trying to figure out what I have missing when calling the object

Comment: "echo ('<pre>'); var_dump($tweet); echo ('</pre>');" Doesn't format the outputted table ??????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: I have managed to reformat the table

Comment: follower_count seems to be in the same depth as screen_name, id, etc... however these are giving the same error.

Comment: try with $tweet->entities->url->followers_count. The strategy you should use is var_dumping the sub arrays until you find the one containing the $followers_count attribute. (i.e. var_dump($tweet->entities) for example). Hope it helps ~

Comment: The same error is being displayed "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78327/discussion-between-answers-seeker-and-user2675041).